# Javascript and html does not work on my computer but does on Winscp and college website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everytime i try to load up my file from my laptop none of my linked files work. I would go to my school course page for my account and exact same code, same file location and no problem at all.

When i try running it from my computer, file:///G:/website/purchasing.html, it says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

but again it is the exact same code used to run from my schools website and WINSCP

Final Project

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate"></script>
<script src="js/final.js"> </script>
<script src="js/final_2.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a `js` folder in your web root?

Comment: Probably because the paths change

Comment: what is webroot sorry i feel its a basic thing to know but i'm still not too familiar with all the terminologies.

Comment: but to having a js file i am 100% sure it is spelled correctly as i've even copied and paste the exact name to the js file

Comment: Did you mean to load jQuery 2.1.4 from Google  _and_  jQuery 1.12.4 from jQuery CDN's ? And load jquery-ui from the cloud and local js folder? Please remove duplicate library loading and see if there is still a problem.

Comment: <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
 <link href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css"  rel="stylesheet">



 
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>


 <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 
 <script src="js/jquery.validate"></script>
 <script src="js/final.js"> </script>
 <script src="js/final_2.js"> </script>

Comment: still no change on the output here. I've gone as far as to copy and paste my friend's code, his works, into mine with the proper adjustments for the js paths and still nothing so i'll probably stick to working on it directly from WINSCP opposed to my laptop